# BeautifulSoup scrape datetime from <time datetime =

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape articles from a website and apart from the title and url I want to have a date when the article was published.

Part of html I want to get data from looks like this:

```
'''<time datetime="2023-10-09T16:46:47+00:00">
                            Yesterday, 18:46
                        </time>'''
```

From this I need 2023-10-09T16:46:47

the code I have is:

```
for article in articles:
title = article.find("a", class_ = "newslink").text.strip()
article_url = urljoin(url,article.find("a")["href"])
date = article.select("time[datetime]")
```

but with this I get:

```
[<time datetime="2023-10-06T06:27:49+00:00">
                                                                Friday, 08:27
                                                        </time>]
```

Comment: What's the url?

Comment: https://www.techpowerup.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`datetime` is the attribute of `time` element, and it can be accessed like this:

```
desired_value = article.select_one("time").get('datetime')
```

or

```
desired_value = article.select_one("time")['datetime']
```

See [BeautifulSoup documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) for more.

Comment: You're welcome @jamiek